# How to rearrange legend position from horizontal (1x4) to 2x2 in ggplot /R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please, find `My script` below.

I have produced this plot

[image]

However, for graphic purposes, I would like to rearrange the horizontal legend to be presented as 2x2. I have manually produced an example of what it should look like in Photoshop:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not been able to locate any clear instructions.

```
My script

ggplot(as.data.frame(out), aes(x = n.fjernet)) + theme +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = model, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = .1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = yhat, col = model),size=1) +

  ggtitle("Lymph node yield") + 

  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 1, xend = 100, yend = 1), lty="dashed", size=0.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 25, y = 1, xend = 25, yend = 0.5), lty="dashed", size=0.5, col="black") +

  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 25, y = 1), size=2, shape=16, col="black", alpha=0.5) +

  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#DAE5F2", "#F9E7E5","#E4F2F3","#FAF1D9"), name = "",
                    labels = c("Overall survival (without LNY)", "Event-free survival (without LNY)","Overall survival (with LNY)", "Event-free survival (with LNY)")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#2C77BF", "#E38072","#6DBCC3","#E1B930"), name = "",
                      labels = c("Overall survival (without LNY)", "Event-free survival (without LNY)","Overall survival (with LNY)", "Event-free survival (with LNY)")) +

  scale_x_continuous(name="", breaks=seq(0,100,by=25), limits=c(0,100), label=c("0","25\nas reference","50", "75", "100")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Hazard ratio", breaks = seq(0.5,1.2,by=.1)) +coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.5,1.25)) +

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size =11), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(t=12)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=12)),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 18,face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14), legend.position="top")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dataset `data(iris)`,part of your code and `guides(col = guide_legend(nrow=2, ncol=2))`, I have achieved the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length))+
   geom_point(aes(y = Sepal.Width, col = Species)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size =11), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(t=12)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=12)),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 18,face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14), legend.position="top")+
        guides(col = guide_legend(title.position = "top",nrow = 2))
```

Be aware that if you do `fill`, then in `guides()` you should also use `fill`. I have used `col` since it is what creates my legend.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try [guides](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html)

Let's say you store your plot in `p`, you could write:

```
p + guides(col = guide_legend(nrow=2, ncol=2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. The legend is still horizontal.

Comment: I will put down an example for you to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

The solution was

```
p + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
```

When storing my ggplot in `p`